# Swift - Enum takes an integer and determine range

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to have an enum that can take an Integer value and use it to determine which case associated with it and return image. Below is something that I want to achieve but I'm not quite know how to implement it. Thank you so much for you help!

```
enum Icon (input: Int) {
//use input value to check which case need to return image name
   case 0...100
   case 101...200
   case 201+

var image: UIImage {
    switch self {
        case .0...100: return UIImage(named: "plane.png")!
        case .101...200: return UIImage(named: "arrow.png")!
        case .201+: return UIImage(named: "logo.png")!
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on using an enum, you can use this:

```
enum Icon: String {
    case plane: "plane.png"
    case arrow: "arrow.png"
    case logo:  "logo.png"

    static func image(for value: Int) -> UIImage {
        let icon: Icon
        switch value {
        case 0...100:
            icon = .plane
        case 101...200:
            icon = .arrow
        case 200...:
            icon = .logo
        default:
            fatalError("Invalid int value")
        }

        return UIImage(named: icon.rawValue)!
    }
}
```

Although surely the following is simpler:

```
func image(for value: Int) -> UIImage {
    switch value {
        case 0...100:
            return UIImage(named: "plane.png")!
        case 101...200:
            return UIImage(named: "arrow.png")!
        case 200...:
            return UIImage(named: "logo.png")!
        default:
            fatalError("Invalid int value")
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I should have thought about a function. Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't it better to use enum for code readability in this case?